# Drupal incorrectly escapes tags in javascript

Tags: php, javascript, html, drupal, escaping

I installed drupal-6.16.
I applied the patch from the post http://drupal.org/node/222926#comment-930745.
It works correctly in simple cases.
But following code of counter is handled incorrectly and counter is now displayed on the page after drupal.

Drupal modifies the string

```
"alt='1Gb.ua counter'><\/a>")</script>
```

to

```
"alt='1Gb.ua counter' />&lt;\/a>")</a></script>
```

The full code of counter follows:

```
<br><br>
Text
<br><br>
<!-- counter.1Gb.ua -->
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
cgb_js="1.0"; cgb_r=""+Math.random()+"&r="+
escape(document.referrer)+"&pg="+
escape(window.location.href);
document.cookie="rqbct=1; path=/"; cgb_r+="&c="+
(document.cookie?"Y":"N");
</script><script language="javascript1.1" type="text/javascript">
cgb_js="1.1";cgb_r+="&j="+
(navigator.javaEnabled()?"Y":"N")</script>
<script language="javascript1.2" type="text/javascript">
cgb_js="1.2"; cgb_r+="&wh="+screen.width+
'x'+screen.height+"&px="+
(((navigator.appName.substring(0,3)=="Mic"))?
screen.colorDepth:screen.pixelDepth)</script>
<script language="javascript1.3" type="text/javascript">
cgb_js="1.3"</script>
<script language="javascript" 
type="text/javascript">cgb_r+="&js="+cgb_js; 
document.write("<a href='http://www.1Gb.ua?cnt=1416'>"+
"<img src='http://counter.1Gb.ua/cnt.aspx?"+
"u=1416&"+cgb_r+
"&' border=0 width=88 height=31 "+
"alt='1Gb.ua counter'><\/a>")</script>
<noscript><a href='http://www.1Gb.ua?cnt=1416'>
<img src="http://counter.1Gb.ua/cnt.aspx?u=1416" 
border=0 width="88" height="31" alt="1Gb.ua counter"></a>
</noscript>
<!-- /counter.1Gb.ua -->
```

Does anybody have this code working?

How should Drupal be fixed to handle this code in correct way?

Other suggestions are welcome.

**EDIT:**

Removing comments does not resolve the issue.

Comment: Why aren't you putting this code in a template / theming function?

Comment: Thanks, it is a good idea, I am only trying Drupal and don't know lot about it. 
Anyway, I think that it is good to have Drupal fixed the issue described and IMHO it can happen in somebody else and already fixed by him.

Comment: posted bug to drupal.org: http://drupal.org/node/741516

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue you describe only when you use the HTML corrector with HTML comments. A quick solution is to remove the comments or disable the HTML corrector.

It would be great if the HTML corrector could handle HTML comments, but IMO HTML comments don't belong in the content of a node etc. If you plan on making markup so complex and special that it needs comments, it's an indicator that it belongs in your theme and not as content.

In your case, you want to add some javascript. Drupal has a function, [`drupal_add_js`](http://api.drupal.org/api/function/drupal_add_js/6), for this, that not only will add the script, but with settings you can cache and minify it for production environment. This will boost performance and general is the way you want to add js to a Drupal site.

Since you are only trying out Drupal, the quickest solution for you now, is just to remove the HTML comments and you should be fine. But if you want to make something meant for a live site, you should check out `drupal_add_js`.

The input filters settings can be found at admin/settings/filters when you edit or create a new filter here you can decide which roles can use it and if the HTML corrector should be applied.

Comment: I just tried to remove comments - it does not help, counter is not visible, <\/a> still escaped.

Comment: That doesn't look like valid HTML. If you want to post invalid HTML remove the HTML corrector in you input field.

Comment: I tried to select "Input format" to "Full Html". It does not help. I also haven't find "HTML corrector" in modules, "Filter" only which can't be disabled because it is code module :(

Comment: I catch it!! thanks! I created separate entry for plain html in "Input formats"

Comment: why is the code incorrect html?  can't realize what is wrong with it.

Comment: accidentally down-voted you answer and can't up-vote it again - it is possible after you edit answer - it could be good if you do so.

Answer (score 0):

It is fixed in drupal 7.x. 
Details are [here](http://drupal.org/node/741516).

Comment: Unless you answer your own question you should add the extra detail in your question. My answer has been edited btw.

Answer (score 0):

Enabling the PHP filter module and setting the input format to PHP solved this issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

I got this issue randomly in `Drupal6` for all content, with or without editor enabled Filtered, Full HTML or PHP.

Found that culprit is the `magic_quotes_gpc` flag in PHP.

Luckily I was able to turn it off easily in `php.ini`, which solved the problem of all kinds of weird escaping.